# javascript for loop increment by > 1 problems

Tags: javascript, html

I have this for loop which works for i and i+1, but i+2 onwards does not work.
The error is:

```
Cannot read property 'logo_sm' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
var rows = '';
for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i=i+2){
    rows += '<tr><td class="logo_sm">' + "<img src='"+jsonObj[i].logo_sm+"'/>" + '</td><td class="logo_sm">' + "<img src='"+jsonObj[i+1].logo_sm+"'/>" + '</td><td class="logo_sm">' + "<img src='"+jsonObj[**i+2**].logo_sm+"'/>" + '</td></tr>';
    i++;
}
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML += rows;
```

In the for loop, if increment is i++ and final column has i+1 instead of i+2 then it works.

Seems simple but still in learning phase. So, I am struggling with it.

Comment: Does the JSON contain an array, or is it an object ?

Comment: Why are you incrementing the i variable at the end of the loop?
Also can we see an example response?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/UuZxg/1/ (neither with arrays of even nor of odd length). You have to provide more information, and even better [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: You MUST do increment of variable in loop statement like for(var i=0;i<5;1++)

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is that you're incrementing both inside and at the top of the loop. When you hit the end of the loop, you're adding 1 to i, then again adding 2 (or 1) up top. If your array or whatever is less than 4 items long, that's going to break it, because array[3] will call for a nonexistent element.

Comment: To debug, you should note that it's essentially telling you jsonObj[i] is nil. Why would that happen?

Comment: Its an array... Incrementing i at the end of the loop was trying various fixes...Here is the response                                                                                     [{"title":"Virtual Magician s Video Podcast",
"logo_sm":"http:\/\/a5.mzstatic.com\/us\/r30\/Podcasts\/v4\/cf\/53\/e1\/cf53e162-f4c7-7842-173d-7f7f2a79fd7e\/mza_854261567010408552.100x100-75.jpg"},
{"title":"this WEEK in TECH Video (small)",
"logo_sm":"http:\/\/a4.mzstatic.com\/us\/r30\/Podcasts2\/v4\/fb\/59\/fc\/fb59fc2d-b1a2-98cf-e1f8-32bae7217912\/mza_5512264877031055372.100x100-75.jpg"}]

Comment: Just to note, the response has a lot more data than what I have provided above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your for loop is setup you will be trying to access array indexes for items that do not exist.

If you initialize i=json.length and have your loop increment by i+2 each time. When i is equal to the length of the JSON object, your loop will be trying to access elements at the length of the JSON object plus 2, which do not exist.

**If you are just trying to output an image in each table row then do the following:**

```
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
var rows = '';
for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++)
{
    rows += "<tr><td class='logo_sm'><img src='"+jsonObj[i].logo_sm+"'/></td></tr>";
}

document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML += rows;
```